# wp_insert_user role not working

Tags: php, user-roles

I have be trying this all day but it is not working how do I set a role for the current user I am inserting with the `wp_insert_user()` function

```
$userdata = array(
'user_login'    =>  $username,
'user_email'    =>  $email,
'user_pass'     =>  $password,
'user_url'      =>  $website,
'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
'last_name'     =>  $last_name,
'nickname'      =>  $nickname,
'description'   =>  $bio,
'role' => 'Editor'
);

$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$WP_array = array (
        'user_login'    =>  $username,
        'user_email'    =>  $email,
        'user_pass'     =>  $password,
        'user_url'      =>  $website,
        'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
        'last_name'     =>  $last_name,
        'nickname'      =>  $nickname,
        'description'   =>  $bio,
    ) ;

    $id = wp_insert_user( $WP_array ) ;

    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $id, 'role' => 'editor') ) ;
```

Since you are looking for working solutions, this one should work, and it is only the helpful answer candidate. I am ware that this may not be the best solution, maybe not even close, but it should work.

Comment: please explain your code

Comment: I copy paste this code from https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_insert_user-does-not-apply-to-roles?replies=3, will modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: but what if i want it to be a s2member level 1

Comment: If you have additional questions please create a new question, it's not fair on prosti to expand the scope indefinitely. The question mentions nothing about s1 membership. @prosti can you edit your answer to explain what you did? Copy paste code isn't an answer, and it doesn't help the OP understand what the problem was

Comment: actually added another answer because of your feedback @TomJNowell

Comment: @TheBeast: Actually member levels are discouraged, now you would need to use capabilities. I set few tips about that in my second replay.

Answer (score 5):

After digging deeper, and checking on my end, I found this script will work just fine.

```
$userdata = array(
'user_login'    =>  $username,
'user_email'    =>  $email,
'user_pass'     =>  $password,
'user_url'      =>  $website,
'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
'last_name'     =>  $last_name,
'nickname'      =>  $nickname,
'description'   =>  $bio,
'role' => 'editor'
);

$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

Yet, there isn't anything mysterious in this script. Looks like the roles need to use lowercase, and you need to blame this function, that I found after days of analysis.

```
/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php
284:    /**
285:     * Whether role name is currently in the list of available roles.
286:     *
287:     * @since 2.0.0
288:     * @access public
289:     *
290:     * @param string $role Role name to look up.
291:     * @return bool
292:     */
293:    public function is_role( $role ) {
```

You can check for your self if you write code like this in `functions.php`.

```
$r = new WP_Roles();
var_dump("editor", $r->is_role("editor"));
var_dump("Editor", $r->is_role("Editor"));
die();
```

You will get the end result like this.

```
string(6) "editor" bool(true) string(6) "Editor" bool(false)
```

This means the `editor` for the role name is OK and the `Editor` is not OK.

We must make a note that if you set an empty role like this `'role' => ""` this will result in setting no roles at all (like @TheBeast experienced at the first place with `Editor` name where at the end no role has been set).

On the other hand if you would omit `'role'` key then your user will take the default role. The default role is usually the `editor`, but it is up to you to customize since that info you can get via `get_option('default_role')`, end set via `set_option` function.

In the past I found indications that the code from @TheBeast would actually work. (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_insert_user-function-user-roles?replies=3)

What is actually important for us is a process of adding roles. You can write like:

```
add_action( 'init', 'plugin_add_role');
function plugin_add_role( 'reviewer', 'Reviewer', $caps );
```

In here your `$caps` capabilities are something like:

```
$caps = array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'edit_others_posts' => true,
        'edit_private_posts' => true,
        'edit_published_posts' => true,
        'read_private_posts' => true,
        'edit_pages' => true,
        'edit_others_pages' => true,
        'edit_private_pages' => true,
        'edit_published_pages' => true,
        'read_private_pages' => true,
    );
```

You can read more about capabilities in the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

just user lower case & in two words roles using underline instead of space

```
'role' => 'Editor'           ------->    'role' => 'editor'

'role' => 'Shop manager'     ------->    'role' => 'shop_manager'
```